# Haskell search list of tuples

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make a program that searches through a list of tuples `(Char, Bool)` and returns true if there are any two conflicting elements within it. Two tuples are conflicting if they have the same value for the first element (`Char`) in the tuple but the second ones are different (`Bool`).

For example

```
[('a', True),('a', False)] returns False , 'a'='a' but True != False
[('a', True),('a', True) returns True. , 'a'='a' and True=True
[('a', True),('a', True), ('b', true), ('c', false)] returns true
```

```
ListofTupels :: [(a,a)] -> [a]
type ListofTupels = [(Char,Bool)]
```

The function is defined like this

```
searchValidity :: ListofTupels -> Bool
```

How to do this?

Comment: Shouldn't the second 2-tuple of the list be `('a', False)` and `('a', True)`?

Comment: it can be anything i just tried to explain that the first value needs to be the same but if the 2nd differs it should trigger a  false return. In your case it will still result in false because the 1st one has false and the 2nd one has true but both are a in first

Comment: Voting to close. Lacks details and clarity. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Clarification: are all tuples assumed to have the same first element? If they are different, how does that effect the desired output?

Comment: they can have diffrent elemets like ("a",..),("b",..),..,("a",..)

Comment: it can be anything the program just looks if there are 2 same elemets with difftrent bool agrument to return false otherwise it returns true

Comment: @Chris can you help me out, i simply cannot do it, please

Comment: The key is to break this down into small problems. Can extract the unique "keys" (the first elements) from the list of tuples? For each "key" can you get a list of values (the second elements)? Now, can you determine if all values in those lists are the same?

Comment: For example, given `[('a', True), ('a', False), ('b', True)]` can you extract `['a', 'b']` as the keys? And then turn that into `[('a', [True, False]), ('b', [True])]`?

Comment: i tried to use a suggestion but i cant get nowhere

Comment: i dont think i can do that, im sorry

Comment: Just do one thing at a time. For the first part, you may find [Data.Set.fromList](https://www.haskell.org/hugs/pages/libraries/base/Data-Set.html#v%3AfromList) and [Data.List.map](https://www.haskell.org/hugs/pages/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3Amap) useful.

Comment: I just cant seem to figure it out , im quite new at haskell

Comment: It definitely takes time. For a taste, the function `fst` will take a tuple with two elements and return the first element. If we may `fst` to `[('a', True), ('a', False), ('b', True)]` we get `['a', 'a', 'b']`. If we create a set from that list, and then convert that set back to a list, we end up with the list `['a', 'b']`.

Comment: Sorry, "map" not "may" in that previous comment.

Comment: The input can be converted into a `Map a [b]`, and then each value `[b]` can be checked for consistency (namely, that each element in the list is equal). The latter is not quite any existing function, but `allEqual :: [a] -> Bool; allEqual = \case { [] -> True; x:xs -> all (== x) xs }` should work.

Comment: can you post the full solved answer please, I'm not sure how to implement that since i get only error when i try to do it this way

Answer (score 4):

Use recursion. An empty list is vacuously valid:

```
type ListofTuples = [(Char,Bool)]

searchValidity :: ListOfTuples -> Bool
searchValidity [] = True
```

An non-empty list consists of a valid tail and a head that doesn't invalidate the list.

```
searchValidity ((c, b):rest) = searchValidity rest && ...
```

I leave filling in `...` as an exercise. The `lookup` function in the Prelude should be useful.

(I leave it as a further exercise to do this in subquadratic time. Using `lookup` at each step slows this down greatly.)

Comment: i literally cannot figure it out, ive been trying to look on the prelude but i have no idea how should i implement that here

Comment: `lookup` can take your list and a character as arguments and return either `Just b` (if the character is found, `b` is the corresponding `Bool` value) or `Nothing`.

Comment: I think `filter` would be more appropriate than `lookup`, since each pair in the remainder of the list with a certain fst must be checked for conflicting snds.

Comment: @jlwoodwa  I'm still stuck at this part, can`t you just show me how to do it? There is no progress, I've been trying to solve it since last night...

Comment: If you have a specific question on how to proceed with what I've already answered, ask a new question. If not, well, there's not much more we can do until you put in some more effort.